# Custom Validator asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am performing both clientside and serverside validation , clientside-jquery and serverside-asp.net
I am using custom validators for checking numeric textboxes.The issue is there are few textboxes that need to check for numeric data and length of the data and also digits after decimal.so i guess i cannot create a common onservervalidate function for all of them as their validation needs differ.
So do i need to use different validation controls for all of them ..can i call three different method on one onservervalidate...
any suggestions thanks

Comment: Normally you would use one validator for each control to be validated.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that means if a textbox requires to be numeric , also length of data should be 10 , and also it should have 2 digits after decimal ,,,, then i will require three custom validators for numeric data ,length and decimal ....Is it so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex class. Within that you only need one function to validate your data with all your requirements.

the regex class is a powerful class where u can define complex patterns that the string has to match. this is one of my simpler regex validator function for my page which returns a boolean if the string send in the parameter (pass) matches the pattern.

```
    Public Function validatepass(ByVal pass As String) As Boolean
    Dim pattern As String = "^\S{6}\S*$"
    Dim MatchString As Match = Regex.Match(pass, pattern)
    If MatchString.Success Then
        Return True
     Else
        Return False
     End If
     End Function
```

it works like this: 
         Dim pattern As String = "^\S{6}\S*$" 
// in this line u define the pattern, ^ is the left end of the string, and $ is the right end
\S{6} is matching the first 6 chars of the string and accepts ANY chars except whitespace chars
\S* does nearly the same, but * means that it can be any number of chars ( again any chars except whitespace chars )

so effectivly this pattern does not accept whitespaces and requires the string to be at least 6 chars long

for a comprehensive guide u should read this :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

and in ur case the regex pattern should be this : ^\d{10},\d{2}$

u can use the same pattern syntax for serverside validation via a function like this, or clientside by creating a customregex validator and using the pattern in the appropriate property.

Comment: could you just elaborate a bit more , as it would be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is there are few textboxes that need to check for numeric
>   data and length of the data and also digits after decimal.

So you basically have three needs...

> 1. Must have some value.
> 2. Numeric value
> 3. Decimal value

---

Here is three in one solution..using [**ReguarExpressionValidation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx)

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValExp" runat="server" 
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)$" 
ControlToValidate="Controlname"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```